# Setting Multi-Notary in corda

Tags: corda

I'm trying to setup Multi-notary in corda, with the help of this below link
https://github.com/corda/corda/tree/master/samples/notary-demo
I downloaded the folder with mkit-m14 branch, after completing all the three steps of command lines for windows In the H2 database there is no table like

```
[NOTARY_COMMITTED_STATES table (for Raft)
```

or

```
NODE_BFT_SMART_NOTARY_COMMITTED_STATES (for BFT)]
```

Comment: Why are you using the `mkit-m14` branch? You should use the `release-V3` branch - that's the latest stable release branch.

Comment: I also tried using release-V3 branch, unable to build files via terminal using command-(gradlew clean build)

Comment: can I try using corda-master branch ?

Comment: You can. What error messages are you getting?

Comment: WARN uanble to instantiate org.fusesource.jansi.windowsAnsioutputstream

Comment: Can you post your Java version? Run `java -version` from the command line.

Comment: Executing test net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNodestest net.corda.node.service.serviceconcurrentUsageTest > operation requiring a transaction work from another FAILED

Comment: java version "1.8.0_151" this is my java version

Comment: That error is just a warning. It should be fine.

Comment: In H2 database there is no NOTARY_COMMITTED_STATES after running these command lines https://github.com/corda/corda/tree/master/samples/notary-demo. How to see the committed states of Notary

Comment: Another Question - In cordapp example folder now there is single Notary, how to add multi-notaries by using the two algorithms ( nodesBFT  or nodesRaft ) what are the steps ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work on a fresh clone of the latest Corda release.

I included the results here, this was on a fresh clone of https://github.com/corda/corda when using the release/os/4.6 branch. It also works on the release/os/4.5 branch.

Just make sure to use the ./gradlew gradle wrapper when you run your test!

Here's what I did:

```
davidawad@boron ~/D/raft-test>release/os/4.6>./gradlew samples:notary-demo:deployNodes
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

> Configure project :
Java version: 1.8
Java source compatibility: 1.8
Java target compatibility: 1.8
Quasar version: 0.7.12_r3
Quasar classifier: jdk8
Building Corda version: 4.6-SNAPSHOT

> Task :confidential-identities:jar
Cordapp metadata not defined for this gradle build file. See https://docs.corda.net/head/cordapp-build-systems.html#separation-of-cordapp-contracts-flows-and-services

> Task :node:capsule:compileJava
Note: /Users/davidawad/Desktop/raft-test/node/capsule/src/main/java/CordaCaplet.java uses internal proprietary API that may be removed in a future release.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:sunapi for details.

> Task :testing:testserver:compileJava
Note: /Users/davidawad/Desktop/raft-test/testing/testserver/src/main/java/CordaWebserverCaplet.java uses internal proprietary API that may be removed in a future release.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:sunapi for details.

> Task :samples:notary-demo:deployNodesBFT
Running Cordform task
Deleting /Users/davidawad/Desktop/raft-test/samples/notary-demo/build/nodes/nodesBFT
Bootstrapping local test network in /Users/davidawad/Desktop/raft-test/samples/notary-demo/build/nodes/nodesBFT
Generating node directory for NotaryService3
Generating node directory for NotaryService2
Generating node directory for AliceCorp
Generating node directory for NotaryService1
Generating node directory for NotaryService0
Waiting for all nodes to generate their node-info files...

... still waiting. If this is taking longer than usual, check the node logs.

> Task :samples:notary-demo:deployNodesBFT
Distributing all node-info files to all nodes
Loading existing network parameters... none found
Gathering notary identities
Generating contract implementations whitelist
New NetworkParameters {
      minimumPlatformVersion=7
      notaries=[NotaryInfo(identity=O=BFT, L=Zurich, C=CH, validating=false)]
      maxMessageSize=10485760
      maxTransactionSize=524288000
      whitelistedContractImplementations {

      }
      eventHorizon=PT720H
      packageOwnership {

      }
      modifiedTime=2020-06-25T21:45:42.014Z
      epoch=1
  }
Bootstrapping complete!

> Task :samples:notary-demo:deployNodesCustom
Running Cordform task
Deleting /Users/davidawad/Desktop/raft-test/samples/notary-demo/build/nodes/nodesCustom
Bootstrapping local test network in /Users/davidawad/Desktop/raft-test/samples/notary-demo/build/nodes/nodesCustom
Generating node directory for AliceCorp
Generating node directory for NotaryService
Waiting for all nodes to generate their node-info files...
Distributing all node-info files to all nodes
Loading existing network parameters... none found
Gathering notary identities
Generating contract implementations whitelist
New NetworkParameters {
      minimumPlatformVersion=7
      notaries=[NotaryInfo(identity=O=Notary Service, L=Zurich, C=CH, validating=true)]
      maxMessageSize=10485760
      maxTransactionSize=524288000
      whitelistedContractImplementations {

      }
      eventHorizon=PT720H
      packageOwnership {

      }
      modifiedTime=2020-06-25T21:46:07.507Z
      epoch=1
  }
Bootstrapping complete!

> Task :samples:notary-demo:deployNodesRaft
Running Cordform task
Deleting /Users/davidawad/Desktop/raft-test/samples/notary-demo/build/nodes/nodesRaft
Bootstrapping local test network in /Users/davidawad/Desktop/raft-test/samples/notary-demo/build/nodes/nodesRaft
Generating node directory for NotaryService2
Generating node directory for AliceCorp
Generating node directory for NotaryService1
Generating node directory for NotaryService0
Waiting for all nodes to generate their node-info files...
Distributing all node-info files to all nodes
Loading existing network parameters... none found
Gathering notary identities
Generating contract implementations whitelist
New NetworkParameters {
      minimumPlatformVersion=7
      notaries=[NotaryInfo(identity=O=Raft, L=Zurich, C=CH, validating=true)]
      maxMessageSize=10485760
      maxTransactionSize=524288000
      whitelistedContractImplementations {

      }
      eventHorizon=PT720H
      packageOwnership {

      }
      modifiedTime=2020-06-25T21:46:45.961Z
      epoch=1
  }
Bootstrapping complete!

> Task :samples:notary-demo:deployNodesSingle
Running Cordform task
Deleting /Users/davidawad/Desktop/raft-test/samples/notary-demo/build/nodes/nodesSingle
Bootstrapping local test network in /Users/davidawad/Desktop/raft-test/samples/notary-demo/build/nodes/nodesSingle
Generating node directory for AliceCorp
Generating node directory for NotaryService
Waiting for all nodes to generate their node-info files...
Distributing all node-info files to all nodes
Loading existing network parameters... none found
Gathering notary identities
Generating contract implementations whitelist
New NetworkParameters {
      minimumPlatformVersion=7
      notaries=[NotaryInfo(identity=O=Notary Service, L=Zurich, C=CH, validating=true)]
      maxMessageSize=10485760
      maxTransactionSize=524288000
      whitelistedContractImplementations {

      }
      eventHorizon=PT720H
      packageOwnership {

      }
      modifiedTime=2020-06-25T21:47:09.766Z
      epoch=1
  }
Bootstrapping complete!

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 4m 51s
105 actionable tasks: 94 executed, 11 up-to-date
davidawad@boron ~/D/raft-test>release/os/4.6>./samples/notary-demo/build/nodes/nodesRaft/runnodes
base debug port set to： 5005
base monitoring port set to: 7005
Starting nodes in /Users/davidawad/Desktop/raft-test/samples/notary-demo/build/nodes/nodesRaft
Starting corda.jar in /Users/davidawad/Desktop/raft-test/samples/notary-demo/build/nodes/nodesRaft/NotaryService2 on debug port 5005
Node will expose jolokia monitoring port on 7005
Running command: osascript -e tell app "Terminal"
    activate
    delay 0.5
    tell app "System Events" to tell process "Terminal" to keystroke "t" using command down
    delay 0.5
    do script "bash -c 'cd \"/Users/davidawad/Desktop/raft-test/samples/notary-demo/build/nodes/nodesRaft/NotaryService2\" ; \"/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java\" \"-Dcapsule.jvm.args=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005 -javaagent:drivers/jolokia-jvm-1.6.0-agent.jar=port=7005,logHandlerClass=net.corda.node.JolokiaSlf4jAdapter\" \"-Dname=NotaryService2\" \"-jar\" \"/Users/davidawad/Desktop/raft-test/samples/notary-demo/build/nodes/nodesRaft/NotaryService2/corda.jar\" && exit'" in selected tab of the front window
end tell
Starting corda.jar in /Users/davidawad/Desktop/raft-test/samples/notary-demo/build/nodes/nodesRaft/AliceCorp on debug port 5006
Node will expose jolokia monitoring port on 7006
Running command: osascript -e tell app "Terminal"
    activate
    delay 0.5
    tell app "System Events" to tell process "Terminal" to keystroke "t" using command down
    delay 0.5
    do script "bash -c 'cd \"/Users/davidawad/Desktop/raft-test/samples/notary-demo/build/nodes/nodesRaft/AliceCorp\" ; \"/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java\" \"-Dcapsule.jvm.args=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5006 -javaagent:drivers/jolokia-jvm-1.6.0-agent.jar=port=7006,logHandlerClass=net.corda.node.JolokiaSlf4jAdapter\" \"-Dname=AliceCorp\" \"-jar\" \"/Users/davidawad/Desktop/raft-test/samples/notary-demo/build/nodes/nodesRaft/AliceCorp/corda.jar\" && exit'" in selected tab of the front window
end tell
Starting corda.jar in /Users/davidawad/Desktop/raft-test/samples/notary-demo/build/nodes/nodesRaft/NotaryService0 on debug port 5007
Node will expose jolokia monitoring port on 7007
Running command: osascript -e tell app "Terminal"
    activate
    delay 0.5
    tell app "System Events" to tell process "Terminal" to keystroke "t" using command down
    delay 0.5
    do script "bash -c 'cd \"/Users/davidawad/Desktop/raft-test/samples/notary-demo/build/nodes/nodesRaft/NotaryService0\" ; \"/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java\" \"-Dcapsule.jvm.args=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5007 -javaagent:drivers/jolokia-jvm-1.6.0-agent.jar=port=7007,logHandlerClass=net.corda.node.JolokiaSlf4jAdapter\" \"-Dname=NotaryService0\" \"-jar\" \"/Users/davidawad/Desktop/raft-test/samples/notary-demo/build/nodes/nodesRaft/NotaryService0/corda.jar\" && exit'" in selected tab of the front window
end tell
Starting corda.jar in /Users/davidawad/Desktop/raft-test/samples/notary-demo/build/nodes/nodesRaft/NotaryService1 on debug port 5008
Node will expose jolokia monitoring port on 7008
Running command: osascript -e tell app "Terminal"
    activate
    delay 0.5
    tell app "System Events" to tell process "Terminal" to keystroke "t" using command down
    delay 0.5
    do script "bash -c 'cd \"/Users/davidawad/Desktop/raft-test/samples/notary-demo/build/nodes/nodesRaft/NotaryService1\" ; \"/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java\" \"-Dcapsule.jvm.args=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5008 -javaagent:drivers/jolokia-jvm-1.6.0-agent.jar=port=7008,logHandlerClass=net.corda.node.JolokiaSlf4jAdapter\" \"-Dname=NotaryService1\" \"-jar\" \"/Users/davidawad/Desktop/raft-test/samples/notary-demo/build/nodes/nodesRaft/NotaryService1/corda.jar\" && exit'" in selected tab of the front window
end tell
No file corda.jar found in /Users/davidawad/Desktop/raft-test/samples/notary-demo/build/nodes/nodesRaft/.cache
Started 4 processes
Finished starting nodes
davidawad@boron ~/D/raft-test>release/os/4.6>./gradlew samples:notary-demo:notarise

> Configure project :
Java version: 1.8
Java source compatibility: 1.8
Java target compatibility: 1.8
Quasar version: 0.7.12_r3
Quasar classifier: jdk8
Building Corda version: 4.6-SNAPSHOT

> Task :samples:notary-demo:notarise
Connecting to the recipient node (localhost:10003)
2020-06-25 17:50:12:517 -0400 [main] INFO net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClient - Startup took 1167 msec
Notary: "O=Raft, L=Zurich, C=CH", with public key: DLHXqvQrTuQ5iUDGjNUue73AMxz256h8zDcFGB7MotS47k
Notarised 10 transactions:
Tx [10AE07..] signed by DLHXqvQrTuQ5iUDGjNUue73AMxz256h8zDcFGB7MotS47k
Tx [D59812..] signed by DLHXqvQrTuQ5iUDGjNUue73AMxz256h8zDcFGB7MotS47k
Tx [A72AA1..] signed by DLHXqvQrTuQ5iUDGjNUue73AMxz256h8zDcFGB7MotS47k
Tx [5B612F..] signed by DLHXqvQrTuQ5iUDGjNUue73AMxz256h8zDcFGB7MotS47k
Tx [48EA8D..] signed by DLHXqvQrTuQ5iUDGjNUue73AMxz256h8zDcFGB7MotS47k
Tx [688989..] signed by DLHXqvQrTuQ5iUDGjNUue73AMxz256h8zDcFGB7MotS47k
Tx [EEAAEF..] signed by DLHXqvQrTuQ5iUDGjNUue73AMxz256h8zDcFGB7MotS47k
Tx [AFC035..] signed by DLHXqvQrTuQ5iUDGjNUue73AMxz256h8zDcFGB7MotS47k
Tx [AC161A..] signed by DLHXqvQrTuQ5iUDGjNUue73AMxz256h8zDcFGB7MotS47k
Tx [4221AF..] signed by DLHXqvQrTuQ5iUDGjNUue73AMxz256h8zDcFGB7MotS47k

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 15s
95 actionable tasks: 5 executed, 90 up-to-date
davidawad@boron ~/D/raft-test>release/os/4.6>
```

good luck !